# JSON Request To WCF

Tags: asp.net, json, wcf, c#-4.0

I am Sending request from json to my wcf service.For Mapping Key value in wcf i have created class and property in that.In Json request there is Key name is ScoreCard.Inside that key there is multiple key and value which is dynamic.

So when i request send to wcf i got it all the keys value except ScoreCard key which is dynamic.I also google it above issue but i get only static key solution not a dynamic.Pls help me to solved issue.

Below are the Json Request and WCF Value get.

```
{"ProspectNo":"1000000073","MakerId":"C136771","MkrDate":"2015/11/26","TranID":"1","ScoreData":{"Client Experience":"1","Stability & Ownership":"7","Property ownership":"22","Co-app/Guarantor":"16","proposed cost":"1800000"}}
```

In Wcf Property Value Get

```
MakerId = "C136771" ,ProspectNo = "1000000073", MkrDate = "2015/11/26", TranID = "1" ,ScoreData = Null
```

Comment: Without the classes in your service contract and your wcf operation implementation it is hard to answer this. This scenario will work but you're actual root-cause is not included in the question